# Problems when installing common-lisp-controller

Tags: software-installation, lisp

I Tried this:

```
nuc ➜  ~  sudo apt install common-lisp-controller
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  darcs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  common-lisp-controller
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/20,8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 119 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package common-lisp-controller.
(Reading database ... 261987 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../common-lisp-controller_7.10+nmu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking common-lisp-controller (7.10+nmu1) ...
Setting up common-lisp-controller (7.10+nmu1) ...
Adding system user `cl-builder' (UID 127) ...
Adding new group `cl-builder' (GID 134) ...
groupadd: failure while writing changes to /etc/group
adduser: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 134 cl-builder' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package common-lisp-controller (--configure):
 installed common-lisp-controller package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 common-lisp-controller
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone have an idea of howto solve this?

```
nuc ➜  ~  ls -al /etc/group
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1061 feb 19 22:00 /etc/group
nuc ➜  ~
```

Comment: Please check permissions of `/etc/group` - add output of `ls -al /etc/group` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert its done.

Comment: Please also check with `lsattr` to see if the file's extended attributes include immutability